# Retrieve data from not working BlueStacks

Tags: data-recovery, bluestacks

An old version of BlueStacks showing the following error and now I can't access my data:

[image]

```
BlueStacks App Player.
Error: CodeTitans.JSon.JSonReaderException: Invalid token found('<' at 1:2)
```

Can this error be fixed? Otherwise, can I recover the data?

Answer (score 1):

The storage used by this virtual machine should be a vdi file.
You can start with [BSTweaker](https://bstweaker.tk/) and its file manager, if the engine starts enough to enable file browsing you should just be able to recover your files.
Also I'm not sure for old version of BStweaker, for new one the file manager is launched from the info tab.

[image: file manager]

If this isn't enough, you have to find a way to open it. this [question](https://superuser.com/questions/342334/mount-vdi-as-drive-in-windows/342339) may be of some use. But it is best if first option works.